# Synchronisation using signals

Tags: c, synchronization, signals, parent-child

what is the way to implement such situation using only **signals (not real-time)**? :

there are N childs (processes, created by `fork()`), 1 parent, and the sync must be like that:

1. parent is waiting for any child signal.
2. every child sends signal to parent, and then blocks until receiving a
       signal from parent
3. parent sends signal to that child, which signal he noticed

I don't know what to do because there are only 2 user defined signals SIGUSR1, SIGUSR2, but I have N childs, so a lot of child should use only one type of signal, and I am afraid of it

any ideas?..

Answer (score 0):

you dont need to use those user defined signals u can send any signal to any child..or parent what you have to do is just to catch that signal using `signal()` or`sigaction()` system function...and from that signal's ISR send signal to particular child

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do synchronization only by signal, (which is not a good idea)
you can use **sigqueue** as sender, and **sigaction** as receiver,
which allow you to append int or pointer to another process.
So receiver can identify sender by the additional information.